# Laravel command not found. Tried to add to PATH but it's not working

Tags: laravel, path, composer-php

I'm trying to install and run Laravel on my Mac machine, but my command line doesn't recognize laravel and responds to all laravel commands with "bash: laravel: command not found". I know that the composer bin folder needs to be added to the $PATH, so I went to my home folder and, since none of the profile files I was told to look for were present, I created a .bash_profile file and added the line "export PATH = $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" to it. However, after saving this and restarting my terminal, laravel is still not recognized. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: There are no command named `laravel` use `artisan` instead. Example : `php artisan serve`

Comment: Have you checked whether the binary is present in `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to do `laravel new blog`. To work you should call `composer global require laravel/installer`.

In case this doesn't work for you use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: I actually installed laravel with `composer global require laravel/installer`. The problem is that this installs laravel to composer's bin file, which is not currently being watched in my $PATH despite having done what other threads here have advised.

Comment: I also use Mac but not doing it with `$PATH`. Try moving composer.phar to `/usr/local/bin`. Try this: https://duvien.com/blog/installing-composer-mac-osx